# DataTable get hidden column value on click

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a datatable that is created with Ajax. However, I do not want all the fields to be displayed and thus I set bVisible to false on the not-so-important field.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#example').dataTable( {
                "bProcessing": true,
                "sAjaxSource": "../DataQueries/FetchAllSubjectsForBrowse.asp",
                "aoColumns": [ 
                    /* Subject Name */ null,
                    /* Address */ null,
                    /* LinkedWithCompany */ { "bVisible": false},
                    /* Work Tel */ null
                ]
            } );
```

However, I want to be able to click on a row to retrieve all the values including from the hidden ones. So I tried the below:

```
$('#example tbody tr').live('click', function () {
             var sTitle;
             var nTds = $('td', this);
             var sSubjectName = $(nTds[0]).text();
             var sSubjectAddress = $(nTds[1]).text();
             var sLinkedWithCompany = $(nTds[2]).text();
             var sWorkTel = $(nTds[3]).text();
});
```

However, when I retrieve the value of sLinkedWithCompany, it instead gives me the value of sWorkTel.

I am a little confused on how to retrieve this hidden value.

Thanks

Comment: console.log(nTds) and post the relevant output

Answer (score 10):

Here is an example of getting row's data on a click.

Suppose you have **Delete** or any button with each row of the table and if you click on the button, get the data of the selected row and perform required operation.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#example tbody').on('click', '.delete', function(){
        var row = $(this).closest('tr');
        var data = $('#example').dataTable().fnGetData(row);
        console.log(data);
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Works well for me, and in exactly the use case you describe: handling click events in buttons embedded in a table row.  Thanks Muhammad.

Answer (score 3):

On the Datatables v1.10.x I've used this method:

Column definition:

```
"columnDefs": [
    { "data": "yourColumnId", "targets": 0, "visible": false
]
```

And then in my function...

```
var rows = $("#tbl").dataTable().fnGetNodes();

for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {

  id = $("#tbl").dataTable().fnGetData(i).yourColumnId;

}
```

I prefer this method instead of the:

```
id = $(rows[i]).find("td:eq(0)").html();
```

Comment: But i want to get the particular row value, here in this code we are iterating the table, can you please help me for getting particular row value.

Answer (score 1):

get current tr data using following code(also returns hidden columns value perfectly):

```
$('#example-table-id').dataTable().fnGetData($('currenttr'));
```

it returns an array and you can access to td values like follow:

```
$('#example-table-id').on('click', 'tbody tr', function(){
    var arr=$('#example-table-id').dataTable().fnGetData($(this)); 
    var Id=arr[0]; //returns first td value 
    var Name=arr[1];//returns second td value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend something like this:

```
var data = [];
$.ajax({url:"../DataQueries/FetchAllSubjectsForBrowse.asp",success:function(result){
  data=result;
}});
var i=0;
 data.forEach(function(d) {d.index=i++;});

$('#example').dataTable( {
            "bProcessing": true,
            "aaData":data, 
            "aoColumns": [ 
                /*index*/
                /* Subject Name */ null,
                /* Address */ null,
                /* LinkedWithCompany */ { "bVisible": false},
                /* Work Tel */ null
            ]
        } );
```

Then in your click handler get the index and then access the record in your original data array

```
$('#example tbody tr').live('click', function () {
         var sTitle;
         var nTds = $('td', this);
         var index = $(nTds[0]).text();
         var record = data[i];
});
```

This is just a starting point, but I hope you get the idea.