# datatables jquery - passing parameters to call ajax

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have a data table with three hidden columns (example: 0,12,13). These columns have index information you need to pass as a parameter in the ajax call. 
What do I need to pass the parameters?
What is the correct way to report this parameter?

`$.ajax({data:RowColumnId_0:?????? , RowColumnId_12:??????, RowColumnId_13:??????  })`

**JS CODE**

```
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#gridList').dataTable({
                bSort: false,
                aLengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "Todos"]],
                iDisplayLength: 50,
                bPaginate: true,
                bJQueryUI: true,
                bFilter: true,
                sPaginationType: "full_numbers",
                aaSortingFixed: [[0, 'desc']],
                oLanguage: {
                    oPaginate: {
                        sFirst: "Primeiro",
                        sPrevious: "Anterior",
                        sNext: "Seguinte",
                        sLast: "&Uacute;ltimo"
                    },
                    sLengthMenu: "Mostrando _MENU_ Registros por pagina",
                    sInfo: "Total de _TOTAL_ Registro(s)",
                    sInfoEmpty: "",
                    sInfoFiltered: "",
                    sSearch: "Buscar",
                    sLoadingRecords: "Carregando...",
                    sProcessing: "Aguarde...",
                    sZeroRecords: "Nenhum Registro Encontrado"
                },
                columnDefs: [
                    { visible: false, targets: [0,12,13] },
                    {
                        targets: [-1],
                        mRender: function(data, full) {
                            if (data === "1") {
                                return '<div class="checkbox"><label><input type=\"checkbox\" checked value="' + data + '"></label></div>';
                            } else {
                                return '<div class="checkbox"><label><input type=\"checkbox\" value="' + data + '"></label></div>';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]

            });

            $('#gridList input[type="checkbox"]').click(function (e)
            {
                if (this.checked) {

                   $.ajax({
                        url: "/Compras/Confronto/AutorizaPedido",
                        data: { IdRowColumn_0:?????? , IdRowColumn_12:??????, IdRowColumn_13:?????? },
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "get",
                        success: function (data) {
                            if (data.Sucesso){
                                toastr.success(data.Mensagem, "Pedido - Autorizado");
                            } else {
                                toastr.error(data.Mensagem, "Pedido");
                            }
                        },
                        complete: function () {}
                    });

            });

        });
```

Comment: you can do concatenation with the url in the ajax

Comment: its as you said, `data: { key: value, key2: value2, etc }`

Comment: Umair, could give an example?

Comment: I do not understand how to get the Id column [0] or column [12] when done checkbox

Comment: Thank you. I solved the problem through the questions.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21717075/datatable-get-hidden-column-value-on-click